# Reload TableViewController from parent

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, parentviewcontroller

I have a TableViewController, lets call it **A**, that is in a container view of another view controller, **B**. I need **A** to reload it's data when a value changes in **B**. I also need it to get this changed value from **B**. Any ideas?

Comment: You simply need to invoke a method in A from your object B instance. This is basically a delegation pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using *notifications*?

So, in **B** – I would do something like:

```
// ViewControllerB.swift

import UIKit

static let BChangedNotification = "ViewControllerBChanged"

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    //... truncated

    func valueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let changedValue = ...
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            BChangedNotification, object: changedValue)
    }

    //... truncated
}
```

Followed up with **A** looking something like this – where `ValueType` is simply the type of the *value* you mentioned:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UITableViewController {

    //... truncated

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        //...truncated

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "onBChangedNotification:",
            name: BChangedNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    //... truncated

    func onBChangedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let newValue = notification.object as? ValueType {

            //...truncated (do something with newValue)

            self.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly – don't forget to [remove the observer](http://natashatherobot.com/ios8-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift/) in **A**'s `deinit` method:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UITableViewController {

    //... truncated 

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    //... truncated
}
```